# python flask...My computer couldn't display

Tags: python, flask

This is code from flask homepages.

```
 from flask import Flask
 app = Flask(__name__)

 @app.route('/')
 def hello_world():
     return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
    app.run(debug=True)
```

when I run the code then enter http://0.0.0.0:5000/
My computer couldn't display...
what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

1) That isn't the code on the flask homepage.

2) Calling `run()` twice won't work.  If the first `run()` will finish executing and get to the second `run()`, wouldn't the second `run(`) finish executing and get to the end of the program and terminate?

`app.run()` is [defined](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#api) like this:

```
run(host=None, port=None, debug=None, **options)

Changed in version 0.10: The default port is now picked from the SERVER_NAME variable.

Parameters: 
host – the hostname to listen on. Defaults to '127.0.0.1'. 
       Set this to '0.0.0.0' to have the server available externally as well. 

port – the port of the webserver. Defaults to 5000 or the port defined in the SERVER_NAME config variable if present.
debug – if given, enable or disable debug mode. See debug.
options – the options to be forwarded to the underlying Werkzeug server. See werkzeug.serving.run_simple() for more information.
```

You can set all those parameters in one `app.run()` call.

3) From the [flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#a-minimal-application):

> If you run the server [with `app.run()`] you will notice that the
>   server is only accessible from your own computer, not from any other
>   in the network. This is the default because in debugging mode a user
>   of the application can execute arbitrary Python code on your computer.
>
> If you have debug disabled or trust the users on your network, you can
>   make the server publicly available simply by changing the call of the
>   run() method to look like this:
>
> ```
> app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
> ```
>
> **This tells your operating system to listen on all public IPs.**

If you try setting the host to `0.0.0.0`, then start your server, flask will display the message:

> - Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

However, that does not mean that 0.0.0.0 is a host name(= an IP address).  `0.0.0.0` means that the server is listening for any public host name(= an IP address) on port 5000.  The url `http://localhost:5000` will also work.

**The bottom line**: Don't use the host 0.0.0.0 unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=SERVER_NAME, debug=None)

Comment: I changed my code like this and I defined SERVER_NAME = 5000

Comment: @asdfghj, How about some examples?  If I use `app.run()`, I can access the page using the url  `http://localhost:5000/` or the url `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`; but if I use my computer's ip in the url: `http://123.456.12.34:5000/`, I cannot retrieve the page.  On the other hand, if I use `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`, I can access the page with *all* the urls above.

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but since I stumbled on it and then FOUND the answer, I thought I'd reply.
The about http://0.0.0.0:5000/ is the DOCKER port 5000.  To access it from outside docker, via your web browser, you first need to MAP the port from external to internal.  To do this, start docker like so:
docker run -p 5555:5000 <dockerImageName>
Then, you should be able to open your browser at the mapped external port:   http://localhost:5555/

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem and i found out that I had to save any code i had written in all my files then after i run then main.py file the web server showed up. So it might be the same situation, just hit cntr-s and save all code in the different .py files then run it